# .htaccess redirection keeping my orginal URL

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, lamp

I would like to have the following setup using .htaccess.

domain.com/test/hello.php or domain.com/index.php or any other link must show only domain.com in the URL.

Kindly share your views on this.

Comment: If you want the browser to go to `domain.com`, how is the server supposed to know to load `/test/hello.php` or `/index.php`?

Comment: I meant that domain must load domain.com/test/hello.php but in the browser URL it must only show domain.com

Comment: "*or any other link must show only domain.com*", it sounds like you want all your links to be accessible with "domain.com" showing in the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As implied by Jon Lin, this is not directly possible as the server cannot guess what content should be loaded. The simple rule of HTTP is that each request has its own response.

Furthermore, it should be noted that, if it were possible (by some kind of magic - perhaps by the use of AJAX), it wouldn't be good for SEO, as Google/Bing/whatever wouldn't be able to index your site.

If you really wanted to *mimic* the behaviour, you could run the following HTML5 History API method in JavaScript:

```
window.history.pushState("", document.title, "/");
```

This will change the address bar to show only your domain name, and will more than likely have side-effects.